# Issues reading NetCDF data into Vector format in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, netcdf, netcdf4

I am trying to write a c++ program to read data from a NetCDF file (and eventually convert into a VDB volume).

I am following the examples given on the NetCDF website (https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/examples/programs/PresTemp4dRd.cpp), and through this I am successfully able to read and store data into an array (in the examples the storage arrays are called pres_in and temp_in. My array is called dbz_in).

The data is simulated radar reflectivity (dbz) in an z,x,y cordinate system, with 5 timesteps.

However, the file I am using has more data than this code can handle. My variable being read is of type float and 40x128x128, which is larger than the stack can handle as an array. My guess is that I need to utilize a vector instead.

This is where I get stuck. GetVar appears to ask for a pointer to the data location - although in the example code it appears the arrays themselves are being passed?

I have attempted to create a pointer to my destination vector (dbz_vec), and pass this to data.getVar.

When setting the dimensions (NLVL, NLAT, NLON) to smaller values (2,12,12), the code executes to completion, and successfully prints the value stored at [1,1,1]. However, the value printed is not the value expected (-6.32932 vs -2.73955), and is shortly followed by a debug error warning: "HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#234) at 0x0102FC00. CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer."

I thought this might be due to the size of the data being read, but 1. it works fine when using the array method, and 2. if I set the dimensions to be the same as the data source (40x128x12) I get a different error, which occurs at the point of writing data with data.getVar: "Exception thrown: write access violation".

Am I on the right path, or is there another way I should perhaps be reading this data before converting to a vector (to be passed to the VDB voxeliser which is currently working fine)?

As you can probably tell I am inexperienced in c++ - I am surprised I have even got to this point to be honest.

```
// We are writing 4D data, a 2 x 6 x 12 lvl-lat-lon grid, with 2
// timesteps of data.
static const int NLVL = 40;
static const int NLAT = 128;
static const int NLON = 128;
static const int NREC = 2;

// Return this code to the OS in case of failure.
static const int NC_ERR = 2;

int main()
{

    // These arrays will hold the data we will read in. We will only
    // need enough space to hold one timestep of data; one record.
    //float dbz_in[NLVL][NLAT][NLON];//<--- This works with data.getVAR and small dimensions (e.g. 2x12x12)

    vector<vector<vector<float>>> dbz_vec(NLVL, vector<vector<float>>(NLAT, vector<float>(NLON)));

    try
    {
        // Open the file.
        NcFile dataFile("D:/CM1 beta/cm1out.nc", NcFile::read);
        
        // Retrieve the variable named "data"
        NcVar data = dataFile.getVar("dbz");

        if (data.isNull()) return NC_ERR;

        //Check initial values of dbz vector to be written to
        for (int f = 0; f < NLON; f++)
        {
            cout << dbz_vec[1][1][f] << endl;
        }

        vector<size_t> startp, countp;
        startp.push_back(0);
        startp.push_back(0);
        startp.push_back(0);
        startp.push_back(0);
        countp.push_back(1);
        countp.push_back(NLVL);
        countp.push_back(NLAT);
        countp.push_back(NLON);
        
        startp[0] = 5; //this is reading the 5th timestep

        float* dbz_ptr = &dbz_vec[0][0][0];

        data.getVar(startp, countp, dbz_ptr); //<--- works when db_ptr is replaced by dbz_in

        for (int f = 0; f < NLON; f++)
        {
            cout << dbz_vec[1][1][1] << endl;

        }
        

        // The file is automatically closed by the destructor. This frees
        // up any internal netCDF resources associated with the file, and
        // flushes any buffers.

         cout << "*** SUCCESS reading example file cm1out.nc!" << endl;
        return 0;

    }
    catch (NcException& e)
    {
        e.what();
        cout << "FAILURE**************************" << endl;
        return NC_ERR;
    }

}
```

Comment: The example code makes use of the fact that `float pres_in[NLVL][NLAT][NLON]` is allocated as a contiguous block of memory. By contrast, an `std::vector` is actually a small object that contains a pointer to heap memory. You give that function the address of one such vector but there is no guarantee that the next vector is adjacent to yours. You may have some luck with [armadillo's `Cube<float>` type](https://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Cube), which promises contiguous memory on the heap.